# Происхождение слова "лицемер"

Tags: этимология

Сижу и раздумываю над словом "лицемер". Первым делом приходит на ум "мерить все по лицам". Но к значению "лживый" это отношения не имеет. Или же "примеряет личины", то есть маски — это мне кажется ближе по смыслу.
А какое происхождение у этого слова на самом деле?

Comment: Я не филолог,но мене всегда интуитивно почему-то казалось что это слово не так применяется у нас, и вместе с тем не мог применить общее название тем кто реально меряет людей по личине, по одежке встречает , маске. Может от этого и есть правильное происхождение слова? Вешает на людей свои ярлыки ,как бы меряет на людей эти лица....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уверен, вы правы в своих догадках, что лицемер – это тот, кто надевает разные лица, скрывая свое настоящее.

Answer (score 2):

По Далю ЛИЦЕМЕРИТЬ, -мерствовать, принимать на себя личину, быть двуличным, облыжным, действовать притворно, обманывать внешностью; прикидываться смиренным, ханжить; льстить кому из своих видов. Лицемерный поступок, притворный, облыжный, где зло скрывается под личиною добра, порок под видом добродетели; человек, лицемер м. -мерка ж. ханжа, притворно набожный или добродетельный; корыстный льстец...

По Фасмеру ЛИЦЕМЕР - от "лицо" + "мена" (меняющий лица, двуличный),  сближено с  "лицо" + "мера".

Со значением согласна, но почему тогда *лицемер*, а не *лицемен*? Мне кажется, что все-таки "лицо" + "мера".

Answer (score 2):

А вот у меня, и у некоторых современных филологов, и у многих историков, несколько другое мнение о происхождении этого слова. Сравните два выражения: "Ну ты и Шумахер!!!"(в принципе, слово "шумахер" уже можно и с маленькой буквы) и "Ну ты и лицемер!". 
"Лицемер", возможно, слово не славянского происхождения, а искажённое имя нарицательное от римского полководца Рицимера (405-472 гг. н.э.). По сути, данный персонаж является последним правителем Рима, и известен именно качествами, укладывающимися в лексическое значение слова "лицемер". В русский язык слово, видимо, пришло из Византии с принятием христианства. На тот момент Рицимер в Византии был популярным персонажем. Находящаяся на грани катастрофы умирающая Византия опасалась появления подобного человека в собственных властных кругах (Рицимер - это такой римский Горбачёв).
А вот этимология слова, принятая в официальных словарях московской филологической школы, извините, "притянута за уши".

Comment: Проблема вашей версии в том, что византийцы называли Рецимера Ре**к**имером и народная этимология, при заимствовании у греков подобного слова, скорей могла перевести его как "меряющий [свою] речь", чем связывать с лицом. Да и в письменных источниках, написание через "Р" должно было бы в этом случае сохраниться

Comment: А имена этих "современных филологов" узнать можно?

Answer (score 0):

На другом форуме  также обсуждается эта тема: "Как произошло слово "лицемерие"? При чем тут "мерить"? Хотела туда составить статейку, но потом решила опубликовать ее запись здесь.

К  ЧЕМУ ЛИЦЕМЕР ПРИМЕРЯЕТ  СВОЁ ЛИЦО

Сколько лиц у лицемерного  человека?  Конечно, у него есть  своё истинное лицо, но есть еще несколько других,  которые он ПРИМЕРЯЕТ. А к кому или  чему он их примеряет?  Вы думаете, что к себе? Нет-нет, нужное лицо он на себя просто надевает, а ПРИМЕРЯЕТ ЕГО К ВАМ. При этом он должен знать,  какое лицо вам должно понравиться.  Если вы добродетельны, то он расскажет вам о своем добронравии и перечислит все добрые дела.  Если  вы не слишком разборчивы в своих поступках, то и он не будет очень строг. Он постарается угадать ваше мнение по разным вопросам и вперед вам его расскажет. Лицемер – тонкий психолог и всегда говорит то, что вы хотите услышать.Непростое это дело – быть лицемером.

Answer (score 0):

Лицемер - это тот, кто примеряет к себе лица (личности) собеседников.

Измеряет (взвешивает, если хотите) лица и действует в своих интересах, учитывая результаты этих измерений. То есть, одному соврёт всенепременно, другому может и соврать, третьему - скажет четвертьправду, четвёртому - полуправду, и только пятому, наиболее опытному, будет вынужден сказать почти всю правду, оставив полную правду при себе на крайний случай.

Answer (score 0):

Лицемерить исторически означало "судить на лице", старославянское "лице" превратилось в русское "лицо", само выражение забылось, сохранив в русском языке лишь наречие "налицо" и наречное выражение "на глазок".

Comment: *Лицемерить исторически означало "судить на лице"* - довольно смелое утверждение. Даже гугл упоминаний о таком выражении не находит. А что оно значило-то?

Comment: Так здесь-то и форма другая. "На лица". ))) А зачем вы под другим аккаунтом удалекнное сообщение восстановили?

Comment: Короче. Вот образец склонения слова "лице" в старославянском http://www.philol.msu.ru/~tezaurus/library.php?view=d&course=1&raz=3&pod=3&par=1 Объясните, какой падеж у вас в выражении "судить на лице" - и как он связан с формой "на лица".

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку появились совсем уже фантастические версии, брошу свои пять копеек.

Да, лицемер - ханжа, фарисей, прячущий чувства, "человек в маске". К лицу вопросов нет.
А вот вопрос о том, что положено в основу второго корня вызывает вопросы.
Фасмер неубедителен, когда возводит к *-měnъ (мена), а форму обїясняет вторичным   сближением с meřa, meřiti (мера).

Собственно, с этим можно было бы согласиться,  если бы не почему-то игнорируемая параллель с Владимѣръ - исходно - великий, обладающий властью и точно так же вторично сближенное с "миром". Если допустить, что "мер" (-mērs) в лицемере того же происхождения, то получается, что "лицемер" - это просто хозяин, владыка своего лица, лицедей.

Грубо говоря, человек, у которого на лице ничего из того, что он реально чувствует, не отображается. А это уже прямая параллель с ханжой и фарисеем.

Версию можно легко опровергнуть или отчасти подтвердить, уточнив когда именно слово попало в активное употребление. Если после XII-XIII то такое объяснение напрочь исключается, семантика того "мера" (-mērs) уже была в языке утеряна. Но у меня таких данных нету.