# Лицемер и лицедей — в чем отличие?

Tags: этимология, семантика

Чем *лицемер* отличается от *лицедея*?

Answer (score 1):

**Из словаря:**

ЛИЦЕДЕЙ,  м. 1. Устар. Актёр. Известный л. 2. Книжн. Притворщик. * Ты был не царь, а лицедей (Тютчев).

ЛИЦЕМЕРНЫЙ,  Отличающийся лицемерием, проявляющий его; **неискренний, двуличный** (о человеке). Л. человек.

**Этимология слов:**

**Лицедей**

Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз., где оно является производным по аналогии с злодей от лицо «лицо, обличие». Буквально — «изображающий лицо кого-л. другого».

**Лицемер**

Происходит от  старославянское лицемѣръ Из *lice и *-měnъ (см. мена), т. е. «меняющий лица, двуличный». Сближено с meřa, meřiti)

Итак, ***лицедей и лицемер*** похожи тем, что они скрывают свое истинное лицо и надевают на себя чужое лицо-маску. Но лицедей – это актер в жизни, он **играет роль или роли,** а **лицемер меняется несколько раз на дню** в зависимости от того, с кем он в данный момент общается.

О происхождении слова "лицемер" говорят много, вот один из вариантов:

К ЧЕМУ ЛИЦЕМЕР ПРИМЕРЯЕТ СВОЁ ЛИЦО

Сколько лиц у лицемерного человека? Конечно, у него есть своё истинное лицо, но есть еще несколько других, которые он ПРИМЕРЯЕТ. А к кому или чему он их примеряет? Вы думаете, что к себе? Нет-нет, нужное лицо он на себя просто надевает, а ПРИМЕРЯЕТ ЕГО К ВАМ. При этом он должен знать, какое лицо вам должно понравиться. Если вы добродетельны, то он расскажет вам о своем добронравии и перечислит все добрые дела. Если вы не слишком разборчивы в своих поступках, то и он не будет очень строг. Он постарается угадать ваше мнение по разным вопросам и вперед вам его расскажет. Лицемер – тонкий психолог и всегда говорит то, что вы хотите услышать.Непростое это дело – быть лицемером. [Просихождение слова "лицемер"](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80/34405#34405)

Comment: а может ли быть, что лицемер, это всё же тот, кто мерит (судит) человека не по его внутреннему (духовному) миру а по его лику?

о чем-то подобном написано в библии https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/csl/45/02/#1-4 https://www.bibleonline.ru/bible/csl/45/02/#9

Comment: Не думаю, ведь лицемер ищет выгоды. Если ему нужно что-то получить от человека, то он старается ему понравиться. Пусть это будут богатые люди, но и у них могут быть разные взгляды: одни презирают нищих, судят по одежде, а другие уже просвещенные и стараются жить по Библии. Лицемер же при общении с этими людьми будет "разделять" их совершенно разные точки зрения.